# how to change the default view of folders to detailed view

Tags: 12.04, unity, directory

is it possible to set default view of all folders to detailed view or list view , instead of doing it every single time

and yeah, i am new to Ubuntu

Comment: Please search for similar post before you post a new question.
This is what you are looking for http://askubuntu.com/questions/81860/how-to-set-default-folder-view-to-list

Comment: @efthialex It's likely the OP *did* search but didn't find that because s/he was using keywords like "detailed" instead of "list." Searching is very good and important but please don't assume people haven't done so, just because they don't find the same results you do. In any case, thanks for finding that question; we can close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @efthialex I also did what Eliah described and found this question using Google. Thanks to OP for posting it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open a **Terminal** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type:

`gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-folder-viewer 'list-view'` and hit ENTER.

There are two more options you can use `'icon-view'` and `'compact-view'`.

Comment: Verified with Ubuntu 16.04